# Is there any difference between __DIR__ and dirname(__FILE__) in PHP?

Tags: php

It looks the same for me,but I'm not sure,

because there are many projects that uses `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

**Their result is exactly the same** ; so, no difference on that.

For example, the two following lines :

```
var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));
var_dump(__DIR__);
```

Will both give the same output :

```
string '/home/squale/developpement/tests/temp' (length=37)
```

But, there are at least two differences :

- **`__DIR__`** only exists with **PHP >= 5.3**

  - which is why **`dirname(__FILE__)`** is more widely used
- **`__DIR__`** is evaluated at compile-time, while **`dirname(__FILE__)`** means a function-call and is evaluated at execution-time

  - so, **`__DIR__`** is *(or, should be)* faster.

As, as a reference, see the [**Magic constants**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) section of the manual *(quoting)* :

> `__DIR__` : The directory of the file.
>   
> If used inside an include, the
>   directory of the included file is
>   returned. 
> This is equivalent to
>   `dirname(__FILE__)`. 
> This
>   directory name does not have a
>   trailing slash unless it is the root
>   directory. 
> (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

Comment: When is `__FILE__` available?

Comment: Not sure, but it's been there for quite some time *(the Magic constants page of the manual says its bahavior has been modified in PHP 4.0.2 ; so I would say it's been there before)*

Comment: __DIR__ and dirname(__FILE__) always strip the last slash, correct?

Comment: Correct, except when the whole path is "/", in which case they don't strip that.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly: **dirname(__FILE__)** is the fastest one, right?

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani no, `__DIR__` is faster.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `__DIR__` and dirname(`__FILE__`) have different outputs under symlinks, but I haven't tested it yet

Comment: With a simple benchmark, executing it 100,000,000 times, I get 17s for dirname(__FILE__) and 4-3s for __DIR__, consistently across 5 tests, so it looks like the difference is considerable (albeit divided by 100,000,000).

Comment: @user198729, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` has been around a looong time. They even work properly on [3.0.11](http://museum.php.net/win32/)....

Comment: @ywarnier, Which engine did you use?

Comment: @PascalMARTIN, Is there anything stopping the compiler/interpreter (e.g. HipHop vm) from evaluating the string `dirname(__FILE__)` as a synonym as `__DIR__`?

Comment: @Pacerier I believe I used PHP 5.5 on the command line. I did the test again with PHP 5.6 CLI. Same result, more or less (factor 4).

Comment: Calling `__DIR__` 1 million times: 0.005666971206665 seconds. Calling `dirname(__FILE__)` 1 million times: 0.062714099884033 - either way, performance is not the problem, I personally like `__DIR__` better for the readability and for being more concise.

Comment: @SteelBrain I tried to reproduce your concern, but it seems `dirname(__FILE__) === __DIR__` was true for all my tests, linking files, linking directories, calling from outside, inside, etc.