# PHP Get name of current directory

Tags: php

I have a php page inside a folder on my website.

I need to add the name of the current directory into a variable for example:

```
$myVar = current_directory_name;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

```
getcwd();
```

or

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

or (PHP5)

```
basename(__DIR__)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

You can use `basename()` to get the trailing part of the path :)

In your case, I'd say you are most likely looking to use `getcwd()`, `dirname(__FILE__)` is more useful when you have a file that needs to include another library and is included in another library.

Eg:

```
main.php
libs/common.php
libs/images/editor.php
```

In your `common.php` you need to use functions in `editor.php`, so you use

`common.php`:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/editor.php';
```

`main.php`:

```
require_once libs/common.php
```

That way when common.php is `require'd` in `main.php`, the call of `require_once` in `common.php` will correctly includes `editor.php` in `images/editor.php` instead of trying to look in current directory where `main.php` is run.

Comment: And `basename(__DIR__)` in PHP 5

Comment: This is giving me the whole path. Is there a way of getting just the directory name?

Comment: @Satch3000 `basename(getcwd())`

Comment: Note that if you use an include or a required, `__DIR__` is the path of the included file and NOT the current directory

Comment: This is a bit misleading. `__DIR__` is basically equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749423/446106).  `basename(__DIR__)` is not.

Answer (score 33):

To get only the name of the directory where script executed:

```
//Path to script: /data/html/cars/index.php
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__)); //"cars"
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path to the directory of the current file.

Example: `/path_to/your_dir/your_file.php`:

```php
// use dirname to get the directory of the current file
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
// $path here is now /path_to/your_dir

// split directory into array of pieces
$pieces = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
// $pieces = ['path_to', 'your_dir']

// get the last piece
echo $pieces[count($pieces) - 1];
// result is: your_dir
```

Comment: The OP seems to have already accepted an answer to their problem. Although you've clearly added value, do you need to vent your furstrations here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting will explain how to make things **bold** avoiding the use of caps, which you have quite rightly pointed out denotes shouting on the internet.

Answer (score 13):

```
echo basename(__DIR__); will return the current directory name only
echo basename(__FILE__); will return the current file name only
```

Comment: As long as you have PHP 5.3 or higher

Answer (score 7):

Actually I found the best solution is the following:

```
$cur_dir = explode('\\', getcwd());
echo $cur_dir[count($cur_dir)-1];
```

if your dir is www\var\path\ **Current_Path**

then this returns **Current_path**

Comment: Watch out, in Linux servers we do not use backslash but the slash.  PHP has a magic constant to make it cross platform, see `PATH_SEPARATOR`

Answer (score 4):

`$myVar = str_replace('/', '', $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);`

libs/**images**/index.php
Result: **images**

Answer (score 4):

To get the names of current directory we can use `getcwd()` or `dirname(__FILE__)` but `getcwd()` and `dirname(__FILE__)` are not synonymous. They do exactly what their names are. If your code is running by referring a class in another file which exists in some other directory then these both methods will return different results.

For example if I am calling a class, from where these two functions are invoked and the class exists in some `/controller/goodclass.php` from `/index.php` then **`getcwd()` will return `/`** and **`dirname(__FILE__)` will return `/controller`**.

Answer (score 0):

I use this line to get the actual file directory name without the path. (For windows)

```
substr(dirname(__FILE__), strrpos(dirname(__FILE__), '\\') + 1)
```

I changed it a bit to work on Linux also

```
substr(dirname(__FILE__), strrpos(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)), '/') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

basename(getcwd());  // returns only the current working dir name.

Comment: FYI: This question is rather old and a good and accepted answer has already been posted the very same day, including a comment with your exact answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997400/801652
Be sure to read all the answers before posting one yourself with the same content