# Get Folder Name Of Current Directory

Tags: php, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Get name of current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997391/php-get-name-of-current-directory)

Today I tried to get the folder name of a directory. I was successful to an extent. But it did not meet my criteria. The code which I have is as follows.

```
<?php
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$foldername = basename($url);
echo $foldername;
?>
```

This returns the final value in an URL. I mean if the URL is `localhost/default` it returns `default` and when the url is `localhost/default/index.php` it returns `index.php`. I want it to return `default` in both the cases.

So is it possible to get the thing which I am expecting ?? Please help me out with that..

Comment: You want [`dirname()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) rather than `basename()`.

Answer (score 4):

[predefined contstants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

You are probably looking for `__DIR__`

if you are looking for the directory in the URL rather than the file system, you could also use

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$dir = $path_parts['dirname'];
```

Comment: Not for this use case.  `__DIR__` is the directory of the current file. The OP is trying to get the directory of a URL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer to reflect it

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$url = "uour_url";
$array = explode('/',$url);
$count = count($array);
echo $array[$count-2];

?>
```

OR you can use getcwd(). This Function will return current directory.

I have not tested it but hope it will helpful to you