# How to Grab the Name of the 2nd Folder Without the Path

Tags: php

The last question was marked as a duplicate so I'm reopening since `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']:` isnt what I'm looking for because it displays the entire path.

I need to just display the name of the 2nd folder alone without the path, without forward slashes and without the pagename

**Here is the structure of the URL:**
http://example.com/sub/**THISFOLDER**/page.php

the domain will change, so I'm looking for a solution that will work for any domain as long as it targets the 2nd folder.

What I want to do is something like this:

`if THISFOLDER is named folder1 then { include("header2.php"); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get name of current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997391/php-get-name-of-current-directory)

Comment: Is this code you're running on that domain, or you're providing a list of other urls? Really, it sounds like you need to be using url rewriting to send those values as parameters into your script.

Comment: @Jessica it will be running on the domain its on but the URL will change often

Comment: Then check my answer @JoeBobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the current folder name use this method:

```
$arr = explode('/', dirname(__FILE__));
$whatyouneed = $arr[count($arr)-1];
```

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? I flagged the post again too, but this guys still reposted it.

Comment: it displays the path still, how do i get rid of everything but the folder at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'http://example.com/sub/THISFOLDER/page.php';
$parts = parse_url($str);
$folders = explode('/', $parts['path']);
var_dump($folders[2]);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "THISFOLDER"
```

I used parse_url so it will work easily regardless of the exact url structure.

Comment: I think that the example url is the current page on the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after - I posted a comment asking him to clarify.

Comment: not sure if OP asked for this, read the last line of question he is asking something like if this=that do this

Comment: Well only one way to find out! @JoeBobby whose answer is right? Jessicas or mine?

Comment: @shehary that was added after I posted.

However he could easily use the same logic with the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` that he's already aware of.

Comment: Plus one for that! Should I remove my answer?

Comment: And actually he could use it with `dirname(__FILE__)` too. I think he just needed to be made aware of `explode`

Comment: Well I'm not the one with the question here so lets see what OP really asked for.

Comment: My answer is what he needs and still someone downvoted it XD.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to get the last folder before the php page. (Even if it is not the second you can use this code).

```
<?php
$thisPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];;
$pattern = '/(\W+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/';
$replacement = '$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Sorry, I don't have a php instance spun up to actually test this, but the way it should work is this:
Looking at it from back to front:
It will find normal word characters and hit the slash, that is accounted for by "/". Then it will look for more normal characters. The '/' is covered, then it will look for any possible non-white space character to cover the rest. You want the middle portion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo explode('\\',getcwd())[count(explode('\\',getcwd()))-1];
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.