# How to get full directory application path?

Tags: php

I've a php application available in this path:

> A:\Utenti\John\Programmi\Bitnami\Wampstack\apache2\htdocs\Log

I want take this full directory path, I actually tried with this:

```
$logPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . rtrim($this->_logPath, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
var_dump($logPath);
```

but I get:

> A:/Utenti/John/Programmi/Bitnami/Wampstack/apache2/htdocs/home/app_test/cfg

and should be:

> A:/Utenti/John/Programmi/Bitnami/Wampstack/apache2/htdocs/Log/home/app_text/cfg

**MORE DETAILS:**

1. *What's `$this->_logPath`?*

is a class variable that contains the following: `home/app_text/cfg`, how you can see it's join to the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`;

2. *Which WebServer I use?*

I'm actually on Bitnami in localhost, but this system will work in any online web server.

Anyway, I almost fix the problem using this:

```
$logPath = __DIR__ . rtrim($this->_logPath, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

that return:

> A:\Utenti\John\Programmi\Bitnami\Wampstack\apache2\htdocs\Log\Log/home/app_test/cfg

how you can see the `Log` folder is duplicated, but I don't think that using `__DIR__` should fix the problem, maybe you guys have a more elegant solution?

Comment: what's in `$this->_logPath`?

Comment: We need a bit more code around the line you gave. It would also help to understand the setup you're using: LAMP, WAMP, etc.

Comment: @RoyFalk, Sure I've updated my question with other details and with another workaround.

Comment: @RyanVincent any hint? I simply want take the app folder complete path..

Comment: Wow, too much code for a simply url :)

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997391/php-get-name-of-current-directory helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add a / :

```
$logPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . rtrim($this->_logPath, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

or you can get rid of the duplicate Log directory by using dirname:

```
$logPath = dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . rtrim($this->_logPath, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```