# PHP include: path relative to where the code is included

Tags: php

I have this code snippet that includes a subpage:

```
function getTabFile($pageName) {
    if ($pageName == null)
        return null;
    if (preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i", $pageName) != 1)
        return null;
    $fileName = getTabFileName($pageName);
    if (file_exists($fileName))
        return $fileName;
    return null;
}
function getDefaultTabFile() {
    return getTabFileName('default');
}
function getTabFileName($page) {
    return __DIR__ . "/page/$page.php";
}
include (getTabFile($_GET['page'] ?? null) ?? getDefaultTabFile());
```

And I want this snippet itself to be included via:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
$path .= "/common/snippet.php"; 
include($path);
```

When I do this the script targets the relative **DIR** of where the snippet is located.

My question is: Is it possible to target the relative **DIR** of the file where the snippet is included?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a php file from another php file as if I opened it directly from the browser (relative path issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525111/running-a-php-file-from-another-php-file-as-if-i-opened-it-directly-from-the-bro)

Comment: Effectively, to ensure your application is compatible in different environments, you would not rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in favor of using `require_once __DIR__ . '/common/snippet.php';` or specify the relative pathing based on the calling script file's depth eg: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/subdir/nested/script.php` would use  `require_once __DIR__ . '/../../common/snippet.php';`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn’t really work for me like that, since I need this script to work no matter in which subfolder file it is included. I would have to find a solution where it isn’t needed to backtrack manually to the root directory. But also, I’m a noob with PHP so maybe I just didn’t get you.

Comment: Correct. What you're after isn't possible since you need to tell PHP where the file resides and the way `include` works with relative pathing. The most reliable method is to specify from the executing script where the include file is located using absolute paths  `__DIR__ . '/../path/to/script.php'`, otherwise you end up running into very quirky behavior. A workaround would be to specify the directory your include file resides using [`set_include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php), then exclude the path, but you will run into other ambiguous issues.

Comment: For clarification `return __DIR__ . "/page/$page.php";`, where  `__DIR__` will ALWAYS be the directory of that script file only. So in your example `__DIR__` will always be `/var/www/common`, resulting in `/var/www/common/page/default.php` as the return value.