# require_once path/to/file.php vs file.php

Tags: php

I'm having the following issue when including a file that includes another file:

```
// path: /ajax/request.php
require_once("../classes/obj/Car.php");


// path: /classes/obj/Car.php;
require_once("Vehicle.php"); // superclass,  this works
require_once("../exception/NoWheelException");  // this doesn't work when Car.php is require_once()'d from /ajax/request.php
```

the problem seems to be that if a file `A` requires a file `B` that requires files `C` and `D`,  it only works if `C` and `D` are used without `"../"`, or `"./"` previous to the file name, when using `require_once()`.

Is there any workaround or any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Ah yes, this is one of those times that PHP can really waste your time. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php The first comment is a good one, recommending the manipulation of working directory: <?php
$wd_was = getcwd();
chdir("/path/to/included/app");
include("mainfile.php");
chdir($wd_was);
?> But Izkata's answer is the more commonly used way to handle this, and its nice.

Comment: thank you, I had already given up and wrote a non-beautiful path like require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "path/to/file/file.php");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `__FILE__` so you know where it's being included from:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../exception/NoWheelException');
```

Where:

```
__FILE__ == "/classes/obj/Car.php";
dirname(__FILE__) == "/classes/obj";
```

Also, a note I didn't know - if your version of PHP is new enough, [`__DIR__` appears to be equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749416/is-there-any-difference-between-dir-and-dirname-file-in-php)

[More info on `__FILE__` and other magic constants here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)