# Difference between plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) and __DIR__

Tags: php, wordpress

Is the trailing slash '/' only difference between these two? If so, I can use `trailingslashit(__DIR__)`?

Answer (score 15):

`plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` This function provides you the **url** of the file directory.

`plugin_dir_url(__DIR__)` This function provides you the **url** plugins folder.

`__FILE__` this magic constant will give you the **path** of file where the file is exist.

`__DIR__` this magic constant will give you the **path** of directory where the file is exist.

`trailingslashit(__DIR__)` this function will return the **path** of directory and add shash after the path of directory.

`plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)`. will give you same result as `trailingslashit(__DIR__)`. and my suggestion to use plugin directory path because it is a wordpress way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type `plugin_dir_path`

Comment: yes you can use both but in wordpress you should use plugin_dir_path

Answer (score 11):

1. **plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )** returns the servers filesystem directory path pointing to the current file, i.e. something along the lines of

**/home/www/your_site/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/includes/**

This can be used for loading PHP files.

more info : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

2. **plugins_url()** returns the web address of the current WordPress installation's plugin folder, i.e. something along the lines of

**http://example.com/wp-content/plugins**

more info : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

3. **plugin_dir_url()** behaves in a very similar fashion to plugins_url(). It also returns a web address, but with a trailing slash, i.e. something along the lines of

**http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/**

The latter two are useful to load images, stylesheets, JS.

more info : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url

Answer (score 7):

Lets untrail what is happening:

The wordpress function is as simple as this:

```
function plugin_dir_path( $file ) {
    return trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) );
}
```

So,

```
include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'xx.php';
```

Is equal to

```
include trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'xx.php';
```

In PHP 5.3, `__DIR__` was introduced as a replacement for `dirname( __FILE__ )`.
If you don't need to support PHP < 5.3 (you don't), it can be reduced to:

```
include trailingslashit( __DIR__ ) . 'xx.php';
```

(also see this : [Is there any difference between __DIR__ and dirname(__FILE__) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749416/is-there-any-difference-between-dir-and-dirname-file-in-php))

As `__DIR__` doesn't return something with a trailing slash, there is no need to do the `trailingslashit` thing. So we can reduce further to:

```
include __DIR__ . '/xx.php';
```

So, to conclude, the following lines all does the exact same thing (on PHP >= 5.3):

```
include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'xx.php';
include trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'xx.php';
include trailingslashit( __DIR__ ) . 'xx.php';
include __DIR__ . '/xx.php';
```

Which is best? I prefer the last one. You don't have to type as much, it is less noisy, and you don't have to worry about what magic is inside that `plugin_dir_path` function. And this is how you usually include files in PHP. Some priests may say you should do it the Wordpress way. Be a rebel!

Comment: You can define a constant in your main plugin/theme file to have the value of `__DIR__` and reuse that constant in other places, so you can be sure your includes & requires are always relative to the plugin/theme root folder. This is useful, because `__DIR__` will point to a different folder in every folder. It can cause issues if you move your files around for some reason. I just create a const `define( 'MYPLUGINNAME_BASEDIR', __DIR__ );` as first things, and reuse that everywhere. My IDE (PHPStorm) can also resolve this properly, making include / require inspections useful again.